# Add a custom command (with a custom icon)

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

Is it possible in IntelliJ/WebStorm to add a custom icon somewhere in a toolbar that runs a custom command, e.g. CLI?

If yes, is it also possible to add this in the projects .idea so that my team members also have this icon without any configuration?

My goal is to add some custom Git commands.

Comment: You can just use [External Tools](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Running+External+Tools+in+PhpStorm) functionality for executing your custom CLI commands -- this will be an IDE-wide setting so others will have to copy such file into IDE config folder. Then you can access such commands via context menus (it has 4 places where such commands can be placed).

Comment: I'm not sure about icons (never used this myself) .. but as far as I'm aware this would not be easily to copy it over (custom toolbar actions) as it would be an IDE-wide settings again which you cannot copy as separate file (as it will be a part of actual IDE customisation config -- hence unique for each user). Tool buttons are rather user unique and not recommended way if yiu want to share this stuff or update it on more-or-less regular basis (or, at least have such possibility)

Comment: Another possible alternative .. that could be actually shared as part of the actual project .. is to code all your custom CLI commands as Gulp/Grunt tasks and execute them that way. Since such file can be placed in project root/subfolder .. it can easily be shared via VCS

Comment: Thanks for the idea, would this also work with NPM scripts? I've tried to add one and it actually works, but I cannot see it within the `.idea` folder (note that we don't share `.idea/workspace.xml` as this causes too much troubles).

Comment: Yes -- you can use NPM scripts as well to execute such tasks -- IDE supports them similarly to Gulp/Grunt. All tasks/scripts are loaded from actual task definitions .. so they are not stored inside `.idea` subfolder. But you can create Run/Debug Configurations (to quickly run specific tasks with possible custom parameters etc) .. and such stuff is placed inside `.idea` (make sure to mark them as Shared .. otherwise they will be stored inside user-specific `workspace.xml` file)

Comment: Ah the "Shared" tick did the trick! :-) Thanks! You can post your comment as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about icons (never used them myself) .. but as far as I'm aware this would not be easily to copy it over (custom toolbar actions) as it would be an IDE-wide setting which you cannot copy as separate file (it will be a part of actual IDE customisation config -- hence uniqueness for each user). Therefore tool buttons are rather user-specific and not recommended way if you want to share this stuff or update it in a future with not much hassle (at very least to have such possibility).

---

Instead you could just use **[External Tools](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Running+External+Tools+in+PhpStorm) functionality** for executing your custom CLI commands -- this will also be *an IDE-wide setting* but each group is stored in separate file.. so others will have to copy such file into IDE config folder. Each such tool can then be accesses via context menus (it has 4 places where such commands can be placed: `Tools` menu and 3 context menus).

---

Another alternative (that could be shared as part of the actual project) is to code all your custom CLI commands as **Gulp/Grunt/NPM script tasks** and execute them that way. Since such files are usually placed in project root (or subfolder) .. they can be easily shared via VCS.

All tasks/scripts are loaded from actual task definition files (`package.json/gulpfile.js/etc`) .. so they are not stored inside `.idea` subfolder. But you can create **Run/Debug Configurations** (to quickly run specific task with possible custom parameters etc) .. and such stuff is placed inside `.idea` (make sure to mark them as "Shared" .. otherwise they will be stored inside user-specific and not-VCS-shareable `workspace.xml` file rather than individual files).